# MS SQL packet size stucked at 590 bytes?

Tags: sql-server, networking, tcp, windows-server-2008-r2, mtu

Not so long time ago, I found out my MS SQL server sends data in packets by 590 bytes, fragmenting large responses in about of 30-50 separated packets, as displayed on [this Wireshark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbCON.png).

I tried to change `max packet size` to 1500, but it has no effect on actual size of tcp packets even after rebooting the server. I tried to carry out some diagnostics and what i found out:

- The problem isn't in clients or server's MTU.
- There is no devices with MTU smaller than 1500 bytes on packets path.
- The `ping -l -f 1472` command from server to any client is succesfull.
- TCP-connections between server and clients almost always have window size in 1024 bytes.

So, a question - why `max packet size` does not affect on actual network packets size? im out of ideas about incorrect hardware or OS setup. Probably, the problem in the MS SQL Server itself? Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

The server running Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.

Clients - Windows 7.

Comment: Excuse me, cannot understand this language.

Comment: Okay, I'll translate it.

Comment: The MTU is the maximum size of the layer-2 payload. You must then subtract for the layer-3, layer-4, and SQL overhead before arriving at the data size which can be transmitted over a link with an MTU of 1500.

Comment: @RonMaupin But there are size of a network frame is displayed on Wireshark screenshot, including all layer2-4 and other protocols, means another 910 bytes available for frame.